# Which framework this web site use?

Tags: user-interface, frameworks, user-experience

I want to know which framework this website use for UI
Website is:
https://app.snapp.ir/?utm_source=Website&utm_medium=homepage

How can I make application like this website?

Answer (score 1):

> which framework this website use

As you can see from the screenshot below, this website was built using [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/)

[image]

> How can I make application like this website?

I suggest you start by [Learning React](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)